# Why will Ubuntu 12.04 LTS not boot with a MegaRaid SAS 9240-4i?

Tags: 12.04

I have a MegaRaid SAS 9240-4i.

After I add this card to the PCI-port Motherboard (Asus P8Z77-v Pro) my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS will not boot.

If change to grub recovery mode I get this error: `timeout: killing /sbin/modprobe -bv pci:v00001000.....`.

Please help me solve this problem!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?